# Conjunction - "or" - meaning. Is it eliminate the previous/afterwards alternative

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

In programming and logic, for example, the "or" is meaning something that may or may not be added to the previous or afterwards: A or B (A only; B only; A and B).

However, in real live conversations it's usually not the case. If someone says A or B, they will probably mean: A without B; B without A.

I search it and couldn't find the proof for this. Can someone help to point this out: what is the real meaning of the "or" in grammar. Is it the first case or the second?

Please provide some links(references) or whatever to back your opinion.

Comment: "In programming and logic, for example, the "or" is meaning something ..." -- wrong. There are several kinds of "OR" in programming and logic. The question is based on an incorrect premise and on oversimplification.

Comment: Kris, what do you mean by `several kinds of "OR" in programming`?

Comment: That one needs to research and find out before posting a question here, as a pre-requisite. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: Kris, what make you think I didn't - if I don't know it, it doesn't mean I didn't "research" it.

Comment: tiju, just show something to convince people here that you tried -- that's required by all of us according to the FAQ. Also, do you know that you can quickly earn some points just by reading the FAQ section? Good Luck.

Comment: For what it's worth, the bitwise `OR` uses the inclusive *or* only, while the bitwise `XOR` uses the exclusive *or* only. Different types of logic and math use different symbols, but each uses only the inclusive *or* or the exclusive *or* (not both).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context will normally determine if it's the inclusive or exclusive *or* that's meant.

Barring that, it needs to be specified if there is room for ambiguity and it makes a difference.

Inclusive:

> Do A or B *or both*.
> Do A or B *or both A and B*.

Exclusive:

> Do *only* A or B.
> Do A or B, *but not both*.

---

From Wikipedia:

> [**Natural language**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)
>
> As with other notions formalized in mathematical logic, the meaning of the natural-language coordinating conjunction *or* is closely related to but different from the logical *or*. For example, "Please ring me or send an email" likely means "do one or the other, but not both". On the other hand, "Her grades are so good that either she's very bright or she studies hard" does not exclude the possibility of both. In other words, in ordinary language "or" (even if used with "either") can mean either the inclusive "or" [inclusive-]or the exclusive "or."

Comment: +1, mainly for understanding the question.

Comment: But wait. See my comment at OP.

Comment: Thank you Jason. So basically the context is what determine if there's silent "only" in the sentence, even if there's no actual "only" word there.

Comment: @tiju Normally, you can make a good guess from the rest of the sentence. In some cases, it doesn't matter if it's interpreted as inclusive or exclusive—it won't change the result. (The first example in the text I quoted, "please ring me or send an email," is a good example. It would normally be interpreted as exclusive—but even if the person did both things, it would still serve the purpose of getting the other person's attention.)

Comment: Sure, I get it, Jason. It's just in live, when you say "A or B", they usually don't think about possibility of "A and B", more likely "only A or only B". Thanks for such a detail answer :)

Comment: @tiji It also depends on if it's a one-time choice. If you visit my house, I might say, "You can use the upstairs bathroom or the downstairs bathroom, it doesn't matter which." Logically speaking, only one or the other can be used at any given time. But there is nothing to prevent you from using one of the bathrooms the first time you need to and the other bathroom the next time. Had I wanted to say that, I would have said, "You can use the upstairs bathroom or the downstairs bathroom. But whichever one you choose is the one you must continue to use during your visit."